How to Use Asyncio to run 2 different async functions
I am writing a script that uses the Graph API for Microsoft to connect to and query user data out of Entra ID in Azure. I have two different functions that I am trying to utilize, one that gets users from a specified group, and one that retrieves a user's display name given their ID value. If I use asyncio.run() to run either one or the other, both will run without issue. But if I try to have both in my script at once, I will get an error on the second one. I am still learning the intricacies of asynchronous programming so cannot for the life of me figure out why I can't get the second call of asyncio.run() to work.
I have this code in my main script that executes a function in another script:
async def get_all_group_members():
            memberListAll = []
            for group in groupList:
                # print(f"We are trying to run group {group}")
                results = await gq.get_group_user(group['GroupID'], graphServiceClient)
                memberDict = {"GroupName":group["GroupName"], "GroupID":group["GroupID"], "MemberList":results}
                memberListAll.append(memberDict)
            return memberListAll
results = asyncio.run(get_all_group_members())

Definition of get_group_user:
memberList = []
members = await graphServiceClient.groups.by_group_id(groupID).members.get()
     if members and members.value:
         for member in members.value:
             user = await graphServiceClient.users.by_user_id(member.id).get()
             if user:
                 memberList.append(user.display_name)
     return memberList

Then later in my main script, I have this second function that's referencing another function from the second script file:
async def get_user_name():
        results = await gq.get_user_by_id(member=member,graphServiceClient=graphServiceClient)
        return results

results2 = asyncio.run(get_user_name())

The defintion of get_user_by_id:
user = await graphServiceClient.users.by_user_id(member).get()
    print(user)

If I comment out everything for the second function, get_group_user, the first function will work just fine. If I comment out everything for the first function, get_all_group_members, the second function will work just fine. It's just when I have both actually run that the second one fails, and I don't know why so can't figure out how to fix it.
Why can I not call asyncio.run() more than once in a script? How do I change my script so that I can successfully run both of those functions asynchronously so I can get the data I need?

Please always post your error message. I can't reproduce "something not working". Generally it should be possible to run asyncio.run(...) twice iff it is executed sequentially and not nested. If you are encountering something like cannot create event loop if there is already an event loop running you probably executed one asyncio.run(...) inside another. This doesn't work.

frankly, I think all tutorials show that you have to put all functions in one function and run it with one run(). And I think run() was constructed to run it from the beginning to the end of program - without exiting and running another run()

If you figured out yourself, you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted! That way question doesn't remain open.

@jupiterbjy I wasn't able to answer my own question when I figured out the solution myself, but see that I can add an answer now so will do that.

Here is the solution that ended up working after I went through more trial and error with my problem.
In order to be able to run both of the async functions, I created another async function that I put both of the other functions in, then called that one function using asyncio.run(). I still don't know why I can't call asyncio.run() two times in the same script without it causing issues, but at least I can move forward with this problem I am trying to solve. Here is what the code looks like now:
async def get_all_group_members():
        memberListAll = []
        for group in groupList:
            # print(f"We are trying to run group {group}")
            results = await gq.get_group_user(group['GroupID'], graphServiceClient)
            memberDict = {"GroupName":group["GroupName"], "GroupID":group["GroupID"], "MemberList":results}
            memberListAll.append(memberDict)
        return memberListAll
        
async def get_user_name():
        member = '<id value>'
        results = await gq.get_user_by_id(member=member,graphServiceClient=graphServiceClient)
        return results
        
async def run_async_functions():
        groupResults = await get_all_group_members()
        usernameResults = await get_user_name()
        return groupResults, usernameResults
            
groupResults, usernameResults = asyncio.run(run_async_functions())

After loading the results of both functions into groupResults and usernameResults, I am then able to print out the values, which means I'll be able to interact with them in the way I need to moving forward.

The docs for asyncio.run indicate it should be called once for a program

This function should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and should ideally only be called once.


To run stuff concurrently, you need to create a Task for each asynchronous function. This will interleave the execution of the two methods.
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(get_all_group_members(), get_user_name())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

But if one async function has to complete before any other, then your self-discovered solution is right, runs them sequentially.
await method_1()
await method_2()
...

